# observable map throws error on return of required data from backend

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

here is my method:

```
 getClinicTrailDropdownData(id: number | 195731): Observable<ClinicTrialSettingProp> {
    return this.http
      .get<ClinicTrialSettingProp>(this.commonPatientURL + id + '/clinic-trials')
      .pipe(map(data => data.data));
  }
```

I am interested in `data.data` as `ClinicTrialSettingProp` how to return that?

but getting an error as :

`Property 'data' does not exist on type 'ClinicTrialSettingProp'.`

Comment: How is `ClinicTrialSettingProp` defined  ?

Comment: it's defined in typescript prop type. but it has no 'data' label. i want to assign incoming data.data as this type

Comment: The type you define in the `get` generic has to include a `data` key !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me:

```
getClinicTrailDropdownData(id: number | 195731): Observable<ClinicTrialSettingProp> {
    return this.http
      .get<{data:ClinicTrialSettingProp}>(this.commonPatientURL + id + '/clinic-trials')
      .pipe(map(data => data.data));
  }
```